# Как переместить запись в начало таблицы?

Tags: postgresql

Например у меня есть записи:

```
   video    |    owner     | id |   channel  
------------+--------------+----+--------------
video2      | nikolay00542 |  1 | nikolay00542
video3      | nikolay00542 |  2 | nikolay00542
video1      | nikolay00542 |  3 | nikolay00542
video4      | nikolay00542 |  4 | nikolay00542
```

Мне нужно переместить video1 в начало таблицы чтобы было так:

```
   video    |    owner     | id |   channel  
------------+--------------+----+--------------
video1      | nikolay00542 |  1 | nikolay00542
video2      | nikolay00542 |  2 | nikolay00542
video3      | nikolay00542 |  3 | nikolay00542
video4      | nikolay00542 |  4 | nikolay00542
```

Количество записей может быть больше

Comment: Указать в запросе требуемый `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы некорректно задали вопрос. Подозреваю, что вы хотите обновить значение столбца `id` основываясь на значениях `video`. Из-за того, что вы не предоставили структуру вашей таблицы, сложно ответить однозначно верно.

Предположим, что столбец `id` в вашем случае не является `PRIMARY KEY` и на него не ссылаются другие таблицы в БД. В этом случае, надо отключить ограничения на уникальность столбца, если они у вас есть. Тогда задачу можно решить с помощью `UPDATE` с вложенным запросом, используя оконную функцию `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
update tbl
set id = t.new_id
FROM (select id, row_number() over (order by video) as new_id from tbl) as t
where tbl.id = t.id;
```

`tbl` — ваша таблица.

В ситуации, когда `id` является `PRIMARY KEY` в таблице, делать какие-либо обновления его не стоит. Правильнее использовать запросы, которые будут возвращать данные в необходимой вам форме. Пример:

```
SELECT
   row_number() over (order by video) as row_id,
   video,
   owner,
   id,
   channel
FROM tbl
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

если вам нужна сортировка в выборке то используйте `order by`

```
select  video,owner,id,channel   from table order by video
```

Comment: Нет, мне не сортировка нужна. Вместо video используется id видео в ютубе например dQw4w9WgXcQ

Comment: Что было представлено в вопросе, на то и ответил